# I was asked to write a code that returns a rectangle that blocks any given polygon between 3 and 10 points (java+arrays+loops)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, polygon, point

**what the method needs to do:** to put it simply, we receive any number of points(from class `Point`) like (1,4)...(7,2) and there can be anywhere from 3 to 10 (if less then 3 it returns `null`) and the methods needs to return the rectangle(which needs to be from class `Polygon`) that blocks the `Polygon` created from the given points, (in other words we get points that create a polygon and  we need to find the rectangle that blocks the polygon),

**the problem**: I believe the code i created should work? but my main problem is I don't know how to write the return command to return those values that are from class Point and print them in this method which is supposed to be class `Polygon`, I have a toString command that prints out everything i just don't know how can i take those point values from SW,SE,NE,NW and insert return them with toString inside the `getBoundingBox()` method

Thanks if you can help i will add the code below, the method i am having trouble with in the return command is `public Polygon getBoundingBox()`

```
//tester
Polygon boundingBox = polygon.getBoundingBox();
String boundingBoxStr = boundingBox.toString();
if (boundingBoxStr.equals("The polygon has 4 vertices:\n((1,0),(7,0),(7,6),(1,6))"))
    System.out.println("\ngetBoundingBox - OK");
else
{
    System.out.println("\nError in getBoundingBox or in toString");
    System.out.println("Your bounding box is:\n" + boundingBox + "\nExpected bounding box is:\nThe polygon has 4 vertices:\n((1,0),(7,0),(7,6),(1,6))");
}
```

```
// instance variables -
private Point [] _vertices;
private int _noOfVertices;

private  final int MAX_VERTICES = 10;
```

```
// constructor
public Polygon()
{
    _vertices = new Point[MAX_VERTICES];
    _noOfVertices = 0;
}
```

```
// add vertex(or point)
public boolean addVertex(int x, int y)
{
    if (_noOfVertices == MAX_VERTICES)
        return false;

    _vertices[_noOfVertices++] = new Point(x,y);
    return true;
}
```

```
//toString
public String toString()
{
    String str = "";

    if(_noOfVertices == 0)  
    {
        str = "The polygon has 0 vertices.";
    }

    int i;
    if(_noOfVertices > 0)  
    {
        str += "The polygon has " + _noOfVertices +  " vertices:" + "\n";
        str += "" + ("(");

        for(i=0; i < _noOfVertices; i++)
            if (i == _noOfVertices-1)
            {
                str += "" + _vertices[i];

            }
            else
            {
                str += "" + _vertices[i] + ",";

            }

        if(i ==_noOfVertices)
        {
            str += "" + (")");
        }

    }
    return str;
}
```

```
public Polygon getBoundingBox()
{
    Polygon rectangle = new Polygon();
    String str = "";

    if(_noOfVertices < 3)
        return null;

    Point SW = _vertices[0];
    Point SE = _vertices[0];
    Point NE = _vertices[0];
    Point NW = _vertices[0];

    for (int i=1; i<_noOfVertices; i++)
    {
        if(_vertices[i].isLeft(SW) && _vertices[i].isUnder(SW))
        {
            SW = _vertices[i];
        }

        if(_vertices[i].isRight(SE) && _vertices[i].isUnder(SE))
        {
            SE = _vertices[i];
        }

        if(_vertices[i].isRight(NE) && _vertices[i].isAbove(NE))
        {
            NE = _vertices[i];
        }

        if(_vertices[i].isLeft(NW) && _vertices[i].isAbove(NW))
        {
            NW = _vertices[i];
        }

    }

    return new Polygon(SW,SE,NE,NW); // if i try to add the points SW,SE,NE,NW to Polygon i get an error "constructor polygon in class polygon can't be 
    // to given types

    // I am suppsoed to print it out like this using toString command:
    // The polygon has 5 vertices: 
    // ((SW,SE,NE,NW))
}
```

Comment: The constructor of `Polygon` that you've shown takes no arguments. Presumably, you need to create a polygon with no points, then add the 4 points (although you've not shown an `add` method), then return it.

Comment: @AndyTurner ohhh wait there is an add method... i didn't think about using it, i will also add it to the post one moment

Comment: You also have the `getBoundingBox()` methods work on the points contained in the polygon itself; I think it should be something like `getBoundingBox(Point[] boundThese)`.

Comment: To @daniu's point, consider what the bounding box of `(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0)` (a square rotated 45 degrees) would be.

Comment: @daniu besides the methods above all i have are calculation of perimeter and area and things like that and we are not allowed to import anything or create any other methods

Comment: iterate over the points - take min / max of both x,y - so you have 4 corners of needed rectangle.

Comment: @user16320675 You're right, you can just return `new Polygon(new Point(Integer.MIN, Integer.MIN), new Point(Integer.MIN, Integer.MAX), new Point(Integer.MAX, Integer.MIN), new Point(Integer.MAX, Integer.MAX)` for any points given. Don't do that OP, it's a joke, of course you need the smallest rectangle.